# What are the type deduction rules for auto*?

Tags: c++, templates, auto, decltype, type-deduction

What are the type deduction rules for `auto*`?

Consider the following:

```
int x = 64;
int* px = &x;

auto* v1 = &x;    // auto => ???    ok v1 is int* ...
auto* v2 = px;    // auto => ???    is v2 int*  ?
auto* v3 = &px;   // auto => ???    is v3 int** ?
```

Just to clarify my question if we split the type deduction into two steps:

1. Deducing the type of "`auto`" itself without (`*`) ... then
2. Deducing the type of the object (`v1`, `v2` and `v3`) after adding the (`*`)

So my two questions are:

1. What will `auto` be deduced to without the (`*`) ?
2. Will `v2` be pointer to `int` (`int*`) and `v3` pointer to pointer (`int**`) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know *template type deduction* you will know almost all there is to `auto` *type deduction*. Because auto type deduction works like template type deduction.

When a variable is declared using `auto`, then `auto` acts as `T` in a template, and the type specifier acts as the *parameter type*:

```
const auto i = 20;
```

Would translate to:

```
template<typename T>
void func(const T param) { ... }
//        ^^^^^^^
```

And with reference:

```
const auto& j = i;
```

Translates to:

```
template<typename T>
void func(const T& param) 
//        ^^^^^^^^
```

---

With pointers, it's the same:

```
auto* v1 = &x;
```

Becomes

```
template<typename T>
void func(T* param)
```

Since `x` is an `int`, then `auto* == int*`.
And `auto* v2 = px;` is also `int*`

Now, the third one you have:

```
auto* v3 = &px;
```

Becomes `int**` since you're taking the address of the pointer.

```
template<typename T>
void func(T** param)
//        ^^^
```

A handy way to see the type of auto is to use what others have mentioned, the `typeid()` function. 
But I like to use `<boost/type_index.hpp>` to show the type correctly:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/type_index.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace boost::typeindex;

int main()
{
    int x = 64;
    int* px = &x;

    auto* v1 = &x;
    auto* v2 = px;
    auto* v3 = &px;
    cout << type_id_with_cvr<decltype(v1)>().pretty_name() << '\n';
    cout << type_id_with_cvr<decltype(v2)>().pretty_name() << '\n';
    cout << type_id_with_cvr<decltype(v3)>().pretty_name() << '\n';
}
```

Which outputs:

```
int*
int*
int**
```

---

There is one *important* difference between auto type deduction and template type deduction, namely `std::initializer_list<>`

Consider these examples:

```
auto i = 1;   // int
auto j(1);    // int
auto k = { 1 }// std::initializer_list<int> !
auto l { 1 }  // std::initializer_list<int> !
```

As you see, using brace initializer with auto can be trouble.
You can however manually write the type before the braces to ensure that the type is correct but I don't see the point in that:

```
auto i = int{ 1 }; // type is int
```

There are [new auto rules](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3922.html) that have been implemented already in Clang 3.8 that makes it possible to use direct-list-initialization with auto (upcoming standard)

Comment: I understand that auto works exactly the same as template ... I actually understand most of type deduction of auto and template but the bit that confuses me is the ( auto* ) and if I would expand my question I would be asking about ( T* ) from the template too  :) ... and unfortunately I dont have boost library :(   but +1 ... thank you

Answer (score 3):

`auto` will deduce to cv-qualified type of the expression given. `auto*` will deduce to the cv-qualified type of the type expression points to - if expression is a pointer - and will fail to compile otherwise.

For given examples, actual type of `v` would be `pointer to int`, same with `v2`, and for `v3` it would be `pointer to pointer to int`.

If your first example would be written as `auto v1 = &px`, type of v1 would remain the same.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `typeid` to answer your question.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    int x = 64;
    int* px = &x;

    auto* v1 = &x;   
    auto* v2 = px;    
    auto* v3 = &px;   
    cout<<typeid(v1).name()<<endl;
    cout<<typeid(v2).name()<<endl;
    cout<<typeid(v3).name()<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Pi
Pi
PPi
```

Pi  --> pointer to integer variable

PPi --> pointer to a pointer to integer variable

Answer (score 0):

The deduction process is the same as a template parameter. If I do:

```
int a = 0;
auto* b = &a;
```

The type of `b` will be `int*`. And writing:

```
auto b = &a;
```

Will result in the same type, `int*`.
In your example, the compiler will in some sort add the missing star. But the simplest form would be to just write `auto`