# Why it does not declare a reference type if 'auto' var is initialized using a function returning reference?

Tags: c++, c++11, auto

When an 'auto' var is initialized using a function that returns a reference, why the var type is not a reference?
e.g. In following example, why type of x is Foo and not Foo& ?

```
class TestClass {
public:
    Foo& GetFoo() { return mFoo; }
private:
    Foo mFoo;
};

int main()
{
    TestClass testClass;
    auto x = testClass.GetFoo(); // Why type of x is 'Foo' and not 'Foo&' ?

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: The link explains how to get the reference, but my question is the **reason** for this behavior.

Comment: That's how type deduction for `auto` works. References and cv-qualifiers are discarded.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++11 "auto" semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542873/c11-auto-semantics)

Comment: @EdgarRokyan is correct. You may use a forwarding placeholder, like: `auto&&`

Comment: We want value semantics without specifying and repeating long type names. That means what Edgar just said.

Comment: What would happen if reference was not discarded?

Comment: Well, it would be rather difficult to *not* have a reference.

Comment: So, got a couple of convincing reasons by StoryTeller and Bathsheba.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because it would be annoying if it worked that way. How, for example, would you specify that you *didn't* want a reference?

When you use `auto`, you need to put `const`, `&`, `&&`, and `volatile` in yourself.

```
auto& x = testClass.GetFoo();
```

is your fix.

Comment: plus, it has the same rules as template deduction and that's how they work.

Comment: @bolov IIRC they're different

Comment: @PasserBy except for initializer lists (but they change it with every standard) they are the same https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36652180/what-are-the-type-deduction-rules-for-auto

Answer (score 3):

C++11 `auto` type inference rules drop reference, const and volatile qualifiers.
However, you may ask C++ compiler to use `decltype` type inference rules to keep all these qualifiers for declaring variable type. In your case it may be:

`decltype(auto) x = testClass.GetFoo();`

But this code can cause some side effects like reference to destroyed object, so you need to keep in mind the real variable type and life time.