# c++ using static member as singleton instance leads to different object

Tags: c++, static, singleton, instance, memory-address

I expected that, when we define a static member as singleton's instance, the `getInstance()` should always return the same object address, so I tried:

```
struct singleton {
    static auto& getInstance() {
        static auto instance = std::make_unique<singleton>();
        return *instance;
    }
};
int main() {
    auto inst1 = singleton::getInstance();
    auto inst2 = singleton::getInstance();
    cout << &inst1 << endl;
    cout << &inst2 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It prints:

```
0x7ffcd729efd8
0x7ffcd729efd0
```

inst1 and inst2 are of different address, meaning I'm creating a new object each time I call `getInstance()`, so it's not a real singleton?

Why different address? I think inst1 and inst2 points to same object! Would you help to explain it?

Comment: `getInstance()` does return the same object every time. But you create different copies of that in `inst1` and `inst2`. `auto& inst1` would create a reference.

Comment: The class still has implicitly generated copy constructor that can be used to copy the objects which you do when creating `inst2`.

Comment: You need to make `singleton` non-copyable.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Why it does not declare a reference type if 'auto' var is initialized using a function returning reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45481105/why-it-does-not-declare-a-reference-type-if-auto-var-is-initialized-using-a-fu) (but I'm not sure if this is really the source of confusion here or not).

Comment: btw `instance` is not a static member of the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class has **implicitly synthesized copy constructor** `singleton::singleton(const singleton&)` that is used when creating `inst2`.

```
//this is copy initialization
auto inst2 = singleton::getInstance(); //works because of accessible copy ctor
```

Same goes for `inst1`.

You can use `auto&` to create an lvalue reference(alias) or make the class non-copyable.